# What does this clause mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence, syntactic-analysis, clauses

What does this clause "...because vocabulary is not the same thing as feeling and plot is light-years from the truth as it is understood by the mind and the heart" mean?

I am confused by the latter part of the clause - "plot is light-years from the truth **as it is understood by the mind and the heart**".

Is this a truncated clause? If not, how else can it be written such that it still conveys the same meaning?

Comment: What do you find troublesome with this part?

Comment: It's a full clause. _As_ is a conjunction, here meaning "in the way that" or "to the degree that".

Comment: Presumably the reviewer finds the plot emotionally unrealistic.

Comment: You need to read the whole interview to understand. << Just using essentially the same plot as one of the very successful writers is hardly likely to result in a convincing and engaging story. >> But lengthy interpretations are off-topic on ELU.

Comment: Preliminary point: your "because" example is not a clause but a preposition phrase ("because" is a prep). "As it is understood" is also not a clause but a preposition phrase modifying "truth". "It is understood ..." is a comparative clause functioning as complement of "as". It can be glossed for comparative purposes as "in the way it is understood ...". Note that "as" is in competition with "like".